# SparkSQL equivalent in BigQuery unix_timestamp

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery, unix-timestamp

I am trying to understand the following line and write its equivalent in BigQuery SQL:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-01-15', 'yyyy-MM-dd') - 900)
```

What exactly is this line in SparkSQL doing and what would be the equivalent of this in BigQuery syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it does the following:

1. converts the string `2019-01-15` to a unix timestamp (# seconds since JAN 01 1970)
2. Subtracts 900 seconds (15 minutes) from the unix timestamp
3. Converts Unix time (`INT64`) to a timestamp data type

Basically, it subtracts 15 minutes from `2019-01-15`. There is a more concise way of doing this with SQL, here is an SQL query that shows them together:

```sql
select 
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", '2019-01-15') original_timestamp,
    -- The equivalent expression to the Spark one you have
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", '2019-01-15')) - 900) original_expression,
    -- Use this instead which does the same thing
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", '2019-01-15'), interval - 15 minute) more_concise
```

**Results:**
[image]